# JSF tailoring webpage according to user permissions

Tags: java, jsf, web, jaas

When a user logs into my website I want to display a div with a user menu, that contains his inbox, notifications, etc. Do I have to use JAAS with JSF to accomplish this? What's the best way to do it? If you could point me in the right direction or maybe some tutorial, or if there's some fancy way to do this instead of using the render attribute. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any issues with using the render attribute based on your security filters. However, others may have better ideas.

Comment: What's wrong with the rendered attribute?

Comment: hey nothing's wrong with rendered attribute, I just wanted to know how to fetch the booleans for it. Should I have a session scoped bean  with a user object, etc. Or how do i combine that with jaas. There's not really good documentation on integrating these specifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your security requirements are not complicated, a simple way of doing this without Jass is by using a **session scoped bean** for the user details.

The div in which you present the logged in\ logged data to the user will be controlled by this bean.

you will not have to use render, depending on what you wish to display to the user.

for example, a message to the user can be displayed always as

```
<h:outputText value="#{UserSession.userMessage}">
```

even if the user is logged out.

I would however consider using the render attribute.

Hope this helps

Added a simple example of session bean.
you can add details to the bean however I would suggest adding the minimum needed.
from this bean you will be able monitor the user.

from java:

```
SessionBean session = (SessionBean)FacesUtils.findBeanInSession("SessionBean");
```

from jsf files, using render on its attributes. i added getLoggedIn method as an example.

java class:

```
public class SessionBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -867309384910092832L;

    private int     userRole;
    private int     userId;
    private String          userName;

    public boolean isLoggedIn ()
    {
        return userId>0 ;   
    }
}
```

faces config:

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>SessionBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.yourPackage.beans.SessionBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm just wondering what's the best way to do it. If render's the way to go then I'll take that. Why do you think it is better than session scoped beans?

Comment: Only if `#{UserSession.userMessage}` doesn't contain any markup. Otherwise it definitely belongs in the view side.

Comment: @user556730 The solutions are not exclusive. The advantage of session scoped bean is that you can keep tabs on your user actions while he is in your site with great ease. I would use both the render attribute on the client side and the session scoped bean to best render and control the user session in your site

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Is there anyway i can get some sample code on this? I still have a couple of doubts. For instance, should the usersession bean contain his username or something? so when he accesses his inbox he can do so by using that?. Or his role?. Also, say a user connects and i have a members menu, should i have component like <h:commandlike etc etc rendered="#{usserBean.notGuest}"

Comment: @user556730 added code examples and some more info. hope it helps

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm going to try this approach. I have yet a lot to learn tho. Thanks man

Comment: @arg20 I'm glad to have helped. feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

HI,

First you have to authenticate the user and decide what permissions user has to access the application. For that may be you will have the variables like flag set in the backing beans. That should be mapped into the render attribute of the specific component.

This is the idea way how we show the pages based on the user permission.